# Fitting three buttons and a background image in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to develop an Android app that should look like an iOS I have done last month. There is a view with a background image and three buttons. The background image has a header part and a footer part, and I need three buttons to stay between these two parts. This is the screenshot from the iOS version and the desired output for my android activity:

[image]

And now what I have now as layout file for the activity:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_pantalla"> >
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/actividades_izq"
        android:text="Actividades" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/agenda_izq"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:text="Agenda" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/suscribete_izq"
        android:text="Recibir Información de Juventud" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want that the layout looks the same or very similar on all devices, in portrait mode.

Now it looks very different depending on the screen size.

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Comment: @Ravi, you mean cutting the backgound image into three parts, one header part, one central part and one bottom part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Linear Layout with weight will solve your problem. Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"> 


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Agenda" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:text="Actividades" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fail"
        android:text="Recibir Información de Juventud" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and let me know the result.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/fondo_pantalla"> >
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/actividades_izq"
    android:text="Actividades"
    layout_weight="1" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/agenda_izq"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:text="Agenda" 
    layout_weight="1"/>

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/suscribete_izq"
    android:text="Recibir Información de Juventud"
    layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the approach from Remees is a little bit better...thank you in any case..

Answer (score 1):

Start by putting button2 to :

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

and button1 to :

```
android:above="@+id\button2"
```

That way at least its centered and can adjust better to screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you, your proposal helps to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is trying to provide on layout for all screensizes and densities. This will hardly be possible. But what you can do is create seperate folders in your res-folder

```
layout-small
layout-medium
layout-large
```

And so on. Please read this article carefully because in your preview you are supporting nearly every screensize and density with just one layout...

Put your custom layouts into the seperate layout-folders to give the users the experience they want. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @novato that's why i posted it as answere. If your Project gets bigger you will Need to provide layouts for different Screen sizes and densities. Enjoy ! ;)